# Call PDO from a function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This function returns a row from the database and prints it in the browser.

```
<?php  

$an_int = 12;    

// If this is an integer

if (is_int($an_int)) 

{

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pushchat', 'pushchat', 'd]682\#%yI1nb3');
    global $conn;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT IdPhoto, device_token, IdUser FROM photos ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 300 ");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);

}

?>
```

How can one call the above code from a standard fucntion? Right now the browser doesn't output anything yet.

```
<?php  

function new_function()

{

$an_int = 12;    

// If this is an integer

if (is_int($an_int)) 

{

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pushchat', 'pushchat', 'd]682\#%yI1nb3');
    global $conn;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT IdPhoto, device_token, IdUser FROM photos ORDER BY IdPhoto DESC LIMIT 300 ");

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($result);
}

}
new_function();

?>
```

The browser does not show output with this current syntax. Is there a way to call my original code from inside the `new_function` function... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in your first file you have declared a `global` variable `global $conn;` I don't exactly know why but anyway that would work without any issue because $conn is in global scope.

But in your second case when you declare your `global` variable inside a function, the function would search for `$conn` which is in global scope instead of the local variable `$conn` which apparently has the connection handle.

remove the `global $conn` from your function and it should work.

more information on variable scopes - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php